# What is the possesive form of "ye"?

Tags: pronouns, possessives, archaicisms

"Ye" is an archaic pronoun that is a plural form of "you".

The possessive form of "you" is "your". The possessive form of "thou" is "thy" (or "thine" before an adjective).

**What is the possessive form of "ye"?** Is it just "your"?

Comment: You've got it backwards. _Ye_ is a form of _you_, and so is _your_. It goes: _I, me, my, mine; thou, thee, thy, thine; we, us, our, ours; ye, you, your, yours_. Notice the patterns here?

Comment: @JohnLawler Do you mean that "ye" is the subject form and "you" is the object form?

Comment: Yes. The plural 1st and 2nd person pronouns have the vowel /i/ in the nominative forms (_we, ye_), whereas the singular ones have it in the objective  (_me, thee_). It's part of the paradigm. Of course this isn't modern English, and nobody ever learns these paradigms or forms or rules as kids; they're all learned in school and also by making stuff up, like in movies, where they don't care about getting speech right. Executive summary: Don't use _ye, thee, thou, thy, thine,_ or any funny suffix, like _goeth_, unless you have studied Old English and know what you're doing.

Comment: @JohnLawler In this case, I'm not talking about Old English. I'm talking about Early Modern English (i.e. the King James Bible) and Modern English (Quaker usages such as in _Moby-Dick_). In those contexts, does what you said still apply?

Comment: Those pronouns are not Old English.  They are Early Modern English.  The Old English second person plural is ġē, ēowic, ēow, ēower.  But the rest of what John said is correct.  And note that one thing John said is that *ye* is the nominative (subject) form.  So what you read in *Moby-Dick* makes sense.

Comment: Ah, yes. I understand now. So the possessive form is "your"?

Comment: These comments would be better as an answer.

Comment: I didn't say they were Old English. In fact there were a lot of paradigms in play, since every local lect had its own history. What I said was don't use those pronouns in speech or writing until you have studied Old English. That will give you some perspective on how languages change.

Comment: @JohnLawler Well, in that case, I certainly agree with the sentiment. There is plenty of horrible misuse of faux-archaism in modern works (for example,  _A Song of Ice and Fire_).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Early Modern English, the nominative (subject) form of the second person plural was *ye*. The rest of the forms of the second person plural are still in use: *you* (objective), *your* (genitive), *your* (possessive).

> "**Ye** have not chosen me, but I have chosen you, and ordained you, that **ye** should go and bring forth fruit, and that **your** fruit should remain: that whatsoever **ye** shall ask of the Father in my name, he may give it you." *(John 15:16 KJV)*

Like many other languages, Early Modern English differentiated between singular and plural second person. The singular was *thou* (nominative), *thee* (objective), *thy*/*thine* (genitive), *thine* (possessive).

*Thine* served as a possessive adjective when the noun that followed began with a vowel, much like *a/an*.

> "Thou hast defiled **thy s**anctuaries by the multitude of **thine i**niquities" *(Ezekiel 28:18 KJV)*

Comment: There's a nice chart at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thou#Declension